# kotlin Retrofit Expecting member declaration Error

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm going to try Retrofit POST using the NAVER Papago translation API.
In the 30th line of the MainActivity.kt file, the error Expecting member description, Name expected occurs.
I searched with the error name, but I can't solve it, so I'm asking this question.

The part where the error occurs is as follows.

```
callPostTransferPapago.enqueue(object:
```

This is MainActivity.kt.

```
package com.example.papagoapi

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    val CLIENT_ID = "clientId"
    val CLIENT_SECRET = "clientSecret"
    val BASE_URL_NAVER_API = "https://openapi.naver.com/"

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL_NAVER_API)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
    val api = retrofit.create(NaverAPI::class.java)
    val callPostTransferPapago = api.transferPapago(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, "ko", "en", "안녕하세요. 이것은 테스트입니다.")

    callPostTransferPapago.enqueue(object: Callback<ResultTransferPapago>{
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ResultTransferPapago>,
            response: Response<ResultTransferPapago>
        ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "성공: ${response.raw()}")
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResultTransferPapago>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "실패: $t")
        }
    })
}
```

Added the resolved code.

```
package com.example.papagoapi

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val CLIENT_ID = "id"
        val CLIENT_SECRET = "secret"
        val BASE_URL_NAVER_API = "https://openapi.naver.com/"

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL_NAVER_API)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val api = retrofit.create(NaverAPI::class.java)
        val callPostTransferPapago = api.transferPapago(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, "ko", "en", "안녕하세요. 이것은 테스트입니다.")

        callPostTransferPapago.enqueue(object: Callback<ResultTransferPapago>{
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResultTransferPapago>,
                response: Response<ResultTransferPapago>
            ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "성공: ${response.raw()}")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResultTransferPapago>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "실패: $t")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the json format response ?

Comment: This is an example of a response. Added at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Is this what you want?

Comment: Can you share also logcat ?

Comment: The build has failed, and there is a huge amount of logcat. Is this what you want?

Comment: Just 3 lines of the logcat that involve

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by what you say. I don't know how to interpret a logcat. I searched the logcat for Parameter Error, but it's still a huge amount.

Comment: Just copy paste that error lines ( 3lines )

Comment: Lines containing 'Expected member descriptions' and 'name expected' descriptions are not found in my logcat.

Comment: The error appears in Problems and Buildoutput.

Comment: Problem solved! Starting with val CLIENT_ID, the code below it must be included in onCreate() {}. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Added the resolved code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your  `callPostTransferPapago.enqueue(...)` call to some activity lifecycle method, eg. `onCreate()`.

Comment: Problem solved! Starting with val CLIENT_ID, the code below it must be included in onCreate() {}. Thank you so much. Added the resolved code.